# How to recreate preview function in MS Teams using c#?

Tags: c#, xaml

I've been searching for ways to create a function where I can preview previous attachments without downloading it just like in MS Teams using C#. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

I have yet to try anything as I can't search for a way to do it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.